# shallow water equations are hyperbolic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I want to show that the shallow water equations of the form
$$\partial_t\left(\begin{array}{c}
h\\
v
\end{array}\right)+\partial_x\left(\begin{array}{c}
hv\\
\frac{1}{2}v^2+gh
\end{array}\right)=0
$$
are hyperbolic, where $h>0$ and $g$ is the acceleration of gravity.

So I have to show that the Jacobi of $f(\left(
\begin{array}{c}
h\\
v\\
\end{array}
\right))$ is diagonalizable. So I computed $$df=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
v~~~~h\\
g~~~v\\
\end{array}
\right)$$ but it is not diagonalizable since the characteristic polynomial does not factor into linear factors. Can anyone help me?

Comment: See [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize+%7B%7Bv%2Ch%7D%2C%7Bg%2Cv%7D%7D)

Comment: thank you very much :)